# Disabling RtMidi examples when building with cmake

Tags: cmake, git-submodules

I am using RtMidi as a git submodule inside a project, I've coded the build system with cmake, but I want to disable RtMidi Examples to build within my project, I've found the lines inside the rtmidi/CMakeLists.txt that enable building the examples.

```
option(RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING "Build test programs" ON)
if (NOT DEFINED RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING OR RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING STREQUAL "")
  set(RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING ${BUILD_TESTING})
endif()

if (RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING)

    #Examples are built here

endif()
```

I think there is no way of building without the examples because the second line on the code above, any thoughts?

Comment: sooo `set(RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING OFF)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk won't the first line override that?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Maybe see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html

Comment: @KamilCuk It did work, I haven't noticed that if the variable already exists then option does nothing, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rtmidi sets the minimum CMake version to 3.10, but sane `option()` behavior (honoring `set()`) wasn't introduced [until 3.13](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html#policy:CMP0077).

No problem, just define the option to `OFF` before it gets the chance.

```
option(RTMIDI_BUILD_TESTING "Build test programs" OFF)
add_subdirectory(rtmidi)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I did not knew that when a variable is already on cache option() gets ignored

Comment: If it didn't, it wouldn't work as a method of setting an option.

Comment: I think it is obvious when you think about it, and also I'm just a noob using CMake hehe

Comment: @ChecheRomo - Everyone starts a noob :) and nothing is obvious about CMake lol